# enable only 1 button in a list?(unity3D)

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have a code which spawns a button(gameobject) with presets everytime I press save.
This button is then saved into a List of gameobjects which I then use to select or deselect them.

I tried to make it so that only 1 button in the list can be selected at a time.
It's working to some degree as If i press the button before the current selected one it works. But if i press any button after the currently selected one it is unable to deselect it.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
public List<GameObject> presetButtons = new List<GameObject>() ;
```

This is the list of Buttons

```
void Update () {

        for (int i = 0; i < presetButtons.Count; i++) {
            if(presetButtons[i].GetComponent<CamUIButtonHandler>().isSelected){
                indicator = i;
                topView.isSelected = false;
            }
        }

        for (int u = 0; u < presetButtons.Count; u++) {
            if(u != indicator)
                presetButtons[u].GetComponent<CamUIButtonHandler>().isSelected = false;
        }



}
```

This is supposed to deactivate the other buttons once 1 is selected.
I'm guessing that there is something  that causes it to not be able to overwrite the currently selected button however I can't seem to find the issue.
Can anyone help me with this? much thanks

Comment: If it should not be possible to select more than one then perhaps a minor redesign should be done. Save the GameObject that is selected in eg. currentSelection. Then when a new one is selected, set the old one to deselected first, then change the currentSelection to point to the new one.

Comment: don't you want to use toggle UI for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like a good place to use UGUI's Toggle And ToggleGroup features. Put a toggle component on each button. Then set each of those buttons' group properties to be the same ToggleGroup. Of course if you aren't using UGUI then this won't be possible.